# Avoiding error/warning "Unlikely argument type"

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a generic type that implements that `Map` interface.

```
public class CountingMap<K> implements Map<K, Double> {
...
/**
 * @see java.util.Map#containsKey(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return backingMap.containsKey(key);
}
...
```

But this gives me an error "Unlikely argument type Object for containsKey(Object) on a Map<K,Double>".  (I know this is usually just a warning, but I have my IDE configured to call this an error, because it often is (for me) and I don't want to change that setting.)

I cannot do this...

```
@Override
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    if ( key instanceof K) {
        return backingMap.containsKey((K) value);   
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Because the type of K is erased at runtime.

The best I can do is:

```
/**
 * @see java.util.Map#containsKey(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    K keyVal = (K) key;
    return backingMap.containsKey(keyVal);
}
```

Does anyone have anything better?  Something that doesn't require the `@SuppressWarnings`?  I mean, it really will fail at runtime if someone calls `containsKey` with an object of the wrong type.  I guess I could catch `ClassCastException`?

Is there an idiomatic way to do this in Java?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? If Java 14+, you may be able to use pattern matching like `if (key instanceof K kkey)` though I'm not sure if it works with generics.

Comment: Would it be viable to subclass an existing `Map` implementation instead of wrapping one, such that you could inherit its `containsKey()` unchanged?  Because if your implementation is going to complain about passing an argument exactly matching the declared type of the parameter of `containsKey()` then I don't think you're going to get away with making that call without suppressing either that warning itself or a warning about an unchecked cast.

Comment: What IDE are you using and how did you configure it to emit this error? `(K) key` *won't* fail at runtime (exactly because it is unchecked), so I'd just do that.

Comment: @Sweeper, it's not the cast that may fail at runtime, but the `containsKey()` invocation.  `Map` documents that that method may throw `ClassCastException` if its argument is of an unsuitable type.  However, that's not a *requirement* to throw, and I'm confident that some implementations will not throw under the circumstances. `HashMap`, for instance.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh. I remembered wrong then. I thought `containsKey` never throws (hence why it takes `Object`).

Comment: Yeah, @Sweeper, `containsKey()` is weird.  But consider how it must be implemented for `TreeMap`, say.  There's no good way for `TreeMap` to test for the presence of the possible key that is not exposed to CCE risk in the event that the argument isn't of a suitable type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> t really will fail at runtime if someone calls containsKey with an object of the wrong type. I guess I could catch ClassCastException?

No, it won't. That cast does nothing. That whole 'generics are erased' thing cuts both ways, the compiler doesn't know what K is.

The  correct action, as always, is to never have compiler errors, only compiler warnings, and consider all warnings as violations that must never make it to production. Exactly for reasons like this (It's also convenient when halfway through writing and e.g. wanting to run the test suite).

Comment: Interesting... I'll have to try that and confirm there really is no CCE.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the IDE rule is at fault given that the 1st code excerpt is perfectly valid Java.

Does this approach get around the rule?

```java
@Override
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    final BiFunction<Map<K, Double>, Object, Boolean> containsKey = Map::containsKey;
    return containsKey.apply(backingMap, key);
}
```

Comment: It's valid Java, but it generates a warning.  I have my IDE configured to treat this warning as an error.